# visual studio Load Testing a page with login with User Count or CSV usernames?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I need to Load Test a page that requires login. I have recorded a login action already. VS 2013 Ultimate has two options for Load test:

1. Under Scenario Wizard -> "Constant Load -> User Count: 25 users".
2. User CSV file with usernames and passwords.

The "Constant Load" option seems to work good as it will ramp up users, but will it perform the logins and with unique session id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options can be chosen independently, you do not have to choose one or the other.

A constant load will not "ramp up users", the test will start with (in your case) 25 users and maintain that number. If you want to "ramp up users" then use the step load pattern.

Independently of the load setting you can data drive the Web Performance Test with a CSV file. There are three methods of reading data from the file. First "Sequential" means data is read in order from the file, after the last line of the file is read then reading starts again at teh top of the file. Next "Unique" also means read in order from the file, but in this case after the last line of the file is read then the test reading that data will stop. Third "random" reads lines in random order.